# smarty template variable not clear

Tags: php, e-commerce, smarty

I am trying to understand developing web apps with PHP and smarty [this is the book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=FTZxXyXrFtUC&lpg=PA100&ots=UJmwl4z8fc&dq=smarty%20function%20load%20parameter%20object&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q=smarty%20function%20load%20parameter%20object&f=false)

there is a file departments_list.tpl

```
{* departments_list.tpl *}
{load_presentation_object filename="departments_list" assign="obj"}
{* Start departments list *}

<div class="box">
  <p class="box-title">Choose a Department</p>
  <ul>
      {* Loop through the list of departments *}
      {section name=i loop=$obj->mDepartments}
        {assign var=selected value=""}
        {* Verify if the department is selected to decide what CSS style to use *}
        {if ($obj->mSelectedDepartment == $obj->mDepartments[i].department_id)}
        {assign var=selected value="class=\"selected\""}
        {/if}
        <li>
        {* Generate a link for a new department in the list *}
        <a {$selected} href="{$obj->mDepartments[i].link_to_department}">
        {$obj->mDepartments[i].name}
        </a>
        </li>
      {/section}
  </ul>
 </div>
{* End departments list *}
```

I do not understand in above file one line which is

```
      {section name=i loop=$obj->mDepartments}
```

how does `name=i` works I what is i initialized to and how can a loop start from i,

secondly above file is using a file function.load_presentation_object.php

```
<?php
// Plug-in functions inside plug-in files must be named: smarty_type_name
function smarty_function_load_presentation_object($params, $smarty)
        {
        require_once PRESENTATION_DIR . $params['filename'] . '.php';
        $className = str_replace(' ', '',ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ',$params['filename'])));
        // Create presentation object
        $obj = new $className();
        if (method_exists($obj, 'init'))
        {
        $obj->init();
        }
        // Assign template variable
        $smarty->assign($params['assign'], $obj);
        }
?>
```

in above file a parameter $params has been used in last line

```
        $smarty->assign($params['assign'], $obj);
```

as far as I can understand from file departments_list.tpl passes on parameter to function.load_presentation_object.php
as

```
{load_presentation_object filename="departments_list" assign="obj"}
```

so when following is called

```
function smarty_function_load_presentation_object($params, $smarty)
```

$params=depratments_list and $smarty=obj

so how does 
            $smarty->assign($params['assign'], $obj);

work what is $params['assign'] in above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{load_presentation_object filename="departments_list" assign="obj"}
```

translated to php will be:

```php
smarty_function_load_presentation_object(
    array(
        'filename' => 'departments_list', 
        'assign'   => 'obj'
    ), 
    $smarty
);
```

Every parameters specified in smarty template are passed as associative array in first argument. Second is always current smarty object.

As for

```
{section name=i loop=$obj->mDepartments}
```

it is simple `for` loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($obj->mDepartments); $i++) {
    $current = $obj->mDepartments[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in  `{section name=i` I have not given i=0 and more over it is name of section if I understood correctly here http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl or is it a convention that what ever name will point to in this case name=i then i has to start with 0

Comment: Sorry for misleading explanation - `i` is name of section, not an integer value in smarty. `i` (note this is used without `$`) will point named section and return current index. If you want to start from index other than 0, use `start=2` as section parameter.